# Java API call while Flyway in Springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, flyway

**I have 2 microservice** (ms-one and ms-two)

In *ms-one*, I have implemented DB migration using flyway. And it is working as expected. i.e: On application start up, all my newly added SQL scripts are triggered and makes the related DB up-to-date. Also, there is one table (permission) in this DB which has 2 column similar to ms-two permission table.

*Example:*
`permission (id, permission_name, service_id, has_access, is_new)`

In *ms-two*, I have an insert API which insert the record in ms-two permission table. The records in this permission table is similar to the records (few column) in ms-one permission table.

*Example:*
`permission (id, permission_name)`

Now, my task is, on server start-up, I should checked is there any new entry in ms-one permission table, if yes, then insert those ID and NAME in ms-two permission table using *INSERT* API. I have a column where I can know wheather the permission is new or not, but wanted to know is it possible to call an API of different microservice in flyway (in my-case, I want to call ms-two INSERT API for permission).

Comment: I'm not sure if Flyway can handle this, but Flyway triggers some events and callbacks. You can try to catch these events and run the insert statement to _ms_two_ manually pre or post flyway execution. To be honest, I haven't tried this by myself so far.

Answer (score 0):

As @FaltFe says, Flyway exposes a series of events during the lifecycle of a migration; you probably want to hook a callback up to `afterMigrate` (happens at the end of a migration) or `afterEachMigrate` (happens at the end of each script).

If you're intending to call another API it is probably easier to write the callback in Java rather than SQL - there's examples here: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/usage/api/hooks#callsbacks